# Proxy server performance improvements?

Tags: javascript, react.js, http, proxy

fairly new to playing around with proxy servers. Wrote a really simple one with Express to help keep some API keys secret so that my front-end app can query the GitHub API. Definitely feels a bit clunky, but is working so far. I really haven't done performance testing before but the way this is implemented it seems like > 1 second round trip. I was wondering if anyone wouldn't mind taking a look and giving me some hints at some basic ways I could improve the performance. One thing I saw come up a few times was piping he request from the endpoint directly back to the requester, but so far I haven't been able to get that to work. Granted I haven't made a huge effort at that.

The proxy server itself is set up as follows:

```js
// Express: ^4.17.1

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

// Initialize app
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Configuration
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))

// Constants
const id = process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
const secret = process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET;
const params = `?client_id=${id}&client_secret=${secret}`



// Route(s)
app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}${params}`;

  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: endpoint,
  })
    .then(response => {
      res.status(200)
      res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error with Axios profile res: ', error)
      res.send({ error })
    })

  return
})

app.post('/repos', (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos${params}&per_page=100`;

  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: endpoint,
  })
    .then(response => {
      res.status(200)
      res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error with Axios repos res: ', error)
      res.send({ error })
    })

  return
})

// App is initialized using app.listen
```

On the frontend we have React, making requests that are proxied tot my server, where they pick up the API keys, and then the server makes a request to the endpoint on the GitHub API. The front-end is responsible for passing a username along to the endpoint. The relevant front-end code is as follows:

```js
function getProfile(username) {
  return fetch('api/profile', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': username })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(profile => {
      if (profile.message) {
        throw new Error(getErrorMsg(profile.message, username))
      }

      return profile
    })
}



function getRepos(username) {
  return fetch('api/repos', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': username })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(repos => {
      if (repos.message) {
        throw new Error(getErrorMsg(repos.message, username))
      }

      return repos
    })
}
```

I can post the React code as well if necessary but it seems like React is not where a bottleneck would be originating - but I'm pretty green at this so that might be mistaken thinking on my part.

There are two requests being fired from the React application simultaneously, the end goal being a general comparison of two GitHub users. I've done this without the proxy and things definitely felt snappier, and I haven't really refactored anything on the front-end aside from pointing the requests at the proxy instead of directly at the GitHub API.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: You aren't doing anything expensive anywhere in the code. If you experience sluggishness, I bet it's just due to ping, which is unavoidable, not due to code issues

Comment: Ok cool. Because I haven't ever really done legitimate performance testing, and given the scale of this application, I thought I would ask before digging into trying to time the requests. It didn't seem inherently expensive, but the little I read about piping requests directly back to front-end sounded like it would make at least part of the request's journey more direct. Thanks for taking a look.